# My Function For Rock, Paper, Scissors Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have a function that is suppose to determine the winner of game. For some reason, it will always print the first if statement, even if it is not correct

I have tried making them all if statements, changing the brackets, and I split all the else if statements up instead of having only 3 and nothing is working.

```
function getElem(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}   

var rounds;

function startGame() {
    rounds = getElem("ROUNDS_TO_PLAY");
    rounds = parseInt(rounds.value);

    document.roundsRemaining = rounds;
    getElem("ROUNDS_REMAINING").value = rounds;
}


/* Responds to user choice button click. */
function userChoice(userButton) {
    updateStats();
    displayUserChoice(userButton);
    var compChoice = getComputerChoice();
    getElem("COMPUTER_CHOICE_OUTPUT").value = compChoice;
    displayComputerChoice(compChoice);

}

function updateStats() {

    rounds=document.roundsRemaining;
    rounds--;
    document.roundsRemaining = rounds;
    getElem("ROUNDS_REMAINING").value = document.roundsRemaining;

    if (document.roundsRemaining < 1) {
        alert("Game over");
        getElem("ROCK_CHOICE").disabled=true;
        //alert(getWinner(userButton, compChoice));
    }

    //alert(getWinner());
    alert (determineWinner());
}

function getComputerChoice() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

    switch (r) {
        case 0: return "ROCK";
        case 1: return "PAPER";
        case 2: return "SCISSORS";
        default: console.log(r + " is not a valid computer choice.");
    }

}


function displayUserChoice(userButton) {
    var uco = getElem("USER_CHOICE_OUTPUT");

    if (userButton == "ROCK") {
        uco.value = "ROCK";
    } else if (userButton == "PAPER") {
        uco.value = "PAPER";
    } else if (userButton == "SCISSORS") {
        uco.value = "SCISSORS";
    } else {
        conosole.log(userButton + " is invalid!!");
    }
}
function determineWinner(userButton,compChoice) {
    if (userButton === compChoice) {
        return 'It\'s a tie!';
    }
    else if (userButton === "ROCK" && compChoice === "PAPER") {
        return 'Computer wins!';
    }
    else if (userButton === 'PAPER' && compChoice === 'SCISSORS') {
        return 'Computer wins!';
    } 
    else if (userButton === 'SCISSORS' && compChoice === 'ROCK') {
        return 'Computer wins!';
    }
    else if (userButton === 'PAPER' && compChoice === 'ROCK') 
    {
        return 'You win!';
    }
    else if (userButton === 'SCISSORS' && compChoice === 'PAPER') {
        return 'You win!';
    } 
    else {
        return 'You win!';
    }

}
```

//Html seperate file

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my game</title>
    <script src="rsp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
</head>

<body>
    Rounds to Play: <input id="ROUNDS_TO_PLAY"><br>
    <input type="button" id="START_GAME" value="Start!" onclick="startGame()">
    Rounds Remaining: <input id="ROUNDS_REMAINING"><br><br><br>

    <input type="button" id="ROCK_CHOICE" value="Rock" onclick="userChoice('ROCK')">
    <input type="button" id="PAPER_CHOICE" value="Paper" onclick="userChoice('PAPER')">
    <input type="button" id="SCISSORS_CHOICE" value="Scissors" onclick="userChoice('SCISSORS')">

    <br>
    User Chose: <input id="USER_CHOICE_OUTPUT" type="text" disabled="true"><br>
    Computer Chose: <input id="COMPUTER_CHOICE_OUTPUT" type="text" disabled="true">
</body></html>
```

The output is suppose to show either computer wins, you win, or its a tie. It shows its a tie every single time.

Comment: Without seeing what `determineWinner` is called with, it's impossible to say exactly what the source of the issue is, but it looks like the two arguments are always the same. Please edit the question into a runnable [MCVE]

Comment: Test the function with statements like `console.log(determineWinner("ROCK", "PAPER")); `You will rapidly discover that this function is not the source of your trouble. My guess is that what you are seeing is unexpected ties based on `undefined === undefined`

Comment: I have tested your determineWinner function. It works as expected. Your proble occurs outside it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  I put the all the functions in i now, as well as the html file i have. Could you please help me?

Comment: @desoares I put the all the functions in i now, as well as the html file i have. Could you please help me?

Comment: `alert (determineWinner());` You are not calling `determineWinner` with anything...

Comment: @JohnColeman I am not sure how to use console.log unfortunately. Is there any other way?

Comment: You could use `alert()` -- but really, you should figure out how to use `console.log()`. Browsers have consoles. Learn how to access them. Great for debugging.

Comment: Yes. I tried alert(dertimineWinner(userButton, compChoice)); before and it doesn't work. Every time I tried that, the program would never get the rounds to play or rounds remaining

Comment: @JohnColeman should I try using console log instead of my if and else if statements?

Comment: @CertainPerformance has already determined the source of your problem. You defined `determineWinner()` to be a function which takes two values, but you are calling it with no values. This means that the missing values are implicitly `undefined`, and since `undefined === undefined` is `true`, your function scores it as a tie. You need to *pass* the relevant values to the function.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes I tried that before and used alert (determineWinner(userButton, compChoice)); and when I would do that, the program doesn't work

Comment: Then -- you need to do more debugging. Your question is starting to morph into a completely different question.

Comment: @JohnColeman No, the question I am asking is still the same. The question was why is my function not working properly and I was stating the methods I tried that were unsuccessful. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getElem(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}   

function userChoice(userButton) {

    displayUserChoice(userButton);
    var compChoice = getComputerChoice();
    getElem("COMPUTER_CHOICE_OUTPUT").value = compChoice;
    updateStats();

}

function updateStats() {

console.log(determineWinner( (document.getElementById("USER_CHOICE_OUTPUT").value), (document.getElementById("COMPUTER_CHOICE_OUTPUT").value)));

}

function getComputerChoice() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

    switch (r) {
        case 0: return "ROCK";
        case 1: return "PAPER";
        case 2: return "SCISSORS";
        default: console.log(r + " is not a valid computer choice.");
    }

}


function displayUserChoice(userButton) {
    var uco = getElem("USER_CHOICE_OUTPUT");

    if (userButton == "ROCK") {
        uco.value = "ROCK";
    } else if (userButton == "PAPER") {
        uco.value = "PAPER";
    } else if (userButton == "SCISSORS") {
        uco.value = "SCISSORS";
    } else {
        conosole.log(userButton + " is invalid!!");
    }
}

function determineWinner(userButton,compChoice) {
    if (userButton === compChoice) {
        return 'It\'s a tie!';
    }
    else if (userButton === "ROCK" && compChoice === "PAPER") {
        return 'Computer wins!';
    }
    else if (userButton === 'PAPER' && compChoice === 'SCISSORS') {
        return 'Computer wins!';
    } 
    else if (userButton === 'SCISSORS' && compChoice === 'ROCK') {
        return 'Computer wins!';
    }
    else if (userButton === 'PAPER' && compChoice === 'ROCK') 
    {
        return 'You win!';
    }
    else if (userButton === 'SCISSORS' && compChoice === 'PAPER') {
        return 'You win!';
    } 
    else {
        return 'You win!';
    }

}
```

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>my game</title> 
</head>

<body>

    <input type="button" id="ROCK_CHOICE" value="Rock" onclick="userChoice('ROCK')">
    <input type="button" id="PAPER_CHOICE" value="Paper" onclick="userChoice('PAPER')">
    <input type="button" id="SCISSORS_CHOICE" value="Scissors" onclick="userChoice('SCISSORS')">

    <br>
    User Choice: <input id="USER_CHOICE_OUTPUT" type="text" disabled="true"><br>
    Computer Chose: <input id="COMPUTER_CHOICE_OUTPUT" type="text" disabled="true">
</body></html>
```